# "Newly found" vs. "New Found"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

What is the grammatically correct way to say the following sentence?

> "I have come away with a **new found** respect for the author..."

or

> "I have come away with a **newly found** respect for the author..."

Comment: I'd suggest _new found_ rather than _newly found_, if for no better reason than that bit of land on the right-hand edge of Canada is _Newfoundland_ not _Newlyfoundland_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are grammatical. That which is *newly found*, has been found recently for the first time. That which is *new found* has been found again with renewed delight and interest.

Comment: An amazing amount of excellent, well-explained answers here, but yours is the one that spoke directly to me and succinctly showed me the true answer: that both were grammatically correct, but one applied more specifically to my context than the other.

Comment: @ShawnHolmes: Kind of you to say so.

Comment: This is interesting and there is something to it, but dictionary definitions for *newfound* do **not** support it; mostly the define *newfound* as *recently discovered, gained* or simply as *newly found*. If you could provide some references I would upvote.

Comment: @Unreason: Under ‘new-found’, the OED gives only ‘newly or recently found, discovered, or invented’ and ‘designating newly discovered land, islands, etc.’ However, definition 5 for the adverb ‘new’ has ‘with past participles used predicatively, or in a postmodifying non-finite clause, in the sense “anew, again, afresh”'. ‘New found’ in the OP’s example is not used predicatively, yet the sense still seems to be of a RENEWED respect, rather than one that has only recently been given.

Comment: I have to praise the answer by Barrie England. I had never considered this subtle but essential difference. Succinct, accurate, and insightful.

Answer (score 9):

I think both are grammatically correct but that "newfound" has simply become far more popular than "newly found". I'd even go so far as to say that "newly found" sounds somewhat strange to the modern ear. Consider the Ngram below, which clearly shows that "newfound" has all but replaced "newly found" in contemporary English.

[image]

Comment: Well, 'all but replaced' is a bit strong. If you look at the frequency of newly found you can see that it actually stagnates with *newfound* going up very much. Coca will tell you that newfound is mostly used in magazines and that's probably the reason why it jumped that high. Newly found is still dominant in academic use.

Answer (score 5):

It's "newfound" - one word. I believe this is the correct term in this case, as "newfound" is an adjective and "newly" is an adverb. Perhaps others know better, though. SE is flagging "newfound" as misspelled, so let's see what others have to say. FWIW, dictionary.com does list "newfound" as "newly found  or discovered: newfound friends." :)

Comment: [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=newfound%2Cnew+found%2Cnewly+found&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows the one-word form "newfound" dominating "new found" and "newly found" since about 1970, at which point its usage increases sharply.

Answer (score 5):

The words "newfound" and "newly found" are not quite synonyms. Or at least, they're usually used for different classes of nouns. Checking Google hits, choosing two random pages (19 & 28), and eliminating proper nouns, 9 out of the first 12 hits for "newfound" were emotions, abilities, or abstract ideas, whereas 11 of the first 12 hits for "newly found" were actual physical objects. The examples are below. So going by these examples, "respect" should be "newfound".

See [this Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=newly+found+species%2Cnewfound+species%2Cnewly+found+feelings%2Cnewfound+feelings&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=10) for more evidence of this distinction (it's *newly found species* but *newfound feelings*). The physical/abstract distinction isn't quite right, because *newfound friends* is more frequent than *newly found friends,* although not as much so as something like *respect*.

> newfound fame
> newfound attitude
> newfound aggressiveness
> newfound urban calm
> newfound respect
> newfound film star
> newfound freedoms
> newfound red galaxies
> newfound abilities
> newfound interest
> newfound maturity
> newfound alien planet
>
> newly found Rosa Parks essay
> newly found ocean floor rare earths
> newly found trend
> newly found Star Wars footage
> newly found orbiting companion [of a planet]
> newly found meteorite
> newly found alien planet
> newly found elderly diabetic subjects
> newly found codices
> newly found Picasso paintings
> newly found treasures
> newly found crack across the Pine Island glacier.

Comment: “Newfound fame” and “newfound respect” are especially common. It seems *newfound* is more idiomatic, used in set phrases, whereas “newly found” is more generic and literal (i.e., “just recently discovered”).

Answer (score 2):

"New found" is an idiom, which is used only in precisely this form. It means "new", but with a connotation of surprise, or of a significant change of view.

I would find "newly found" strange (except in the literal sense of something that has just been discovered).

Comment: This was my first thought, but the second sentence seems OK if the article is dropped: "I have come away with newly found respect for the author..."

Comment: @Kith: I don't think the article really affects anything. *Newly* is a bit less common than *new*, but I can't see any marked tendency [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new+found+respect%2Cnewly+found+respect&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for it to be more likely to be preceded by "a".